# Zxing Barcode scanner android Camara not working

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am using zxing Barcode scanner with my android app. it was working properly. but from last few days when i am calling the app, app is called but camera is not geting open. but when i am clicking on help or setting button and comming back to first screen camara is open and i am able to scan the barcode.

I want to know the problem is with my app or zxing barcode scanner app. is there is any probleem with android permission or some thing else

Here is my code

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
      switch(arg0.getId())
      {
        case R.id.scan_button:
            if(arg0.getId()==R.id.scan_button)
            {
                IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(Barcode.this);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    try
    {
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

       if (scanningResult != null) 
        {
            scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            tvPrn.setText(scanContent.toUpperCase());
            barCdDone.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            barCdDone.setText("");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        barCdDone.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code along with it

Comment: Your activity is `Barcode`?

Comment: I suggest you use [ZXing-barcode-embbed](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded)

Comment: Have you changed targetSdk or API version of your phone/emulator since the time it worked fine?